# Executar uma função após adicionar item a store de uma tree

Tags: javascript, extjs

Eu tenho 2 Trees no meu projeto feito com ExtJs4, e uma das Trees é adicionado valor no `store` após um evento. Eu gostaria de logo que o valor for adicionado no `store` da primeira `tree`, a segunda reatualizasse com os novos valores da primeira. Como se fosse um `callBack` depois que eu uso a função `appendChild`.

Código quando adiciono valor na primeira Tree:

```
...
handler: function(){
            var treeProc = Ext.getCmp('int-proc').store;
            var ttP = treeProc.getRootNode();

            var treeInt = Ext.getCmp('int-int').store;
            var ttI = treeInt.getRootNode();

        Ext.each(ttI.childNodes, function(node){
            var plop = node.data['text'].substr(-3);
            var change = node.data['text'].replace(plop, 'doc');

            ttP.getChildAt(0).appendChild({
                txt: change,
                tipo: 'intimacao',
                id: "9898",
                data: '10/06/2014',
                leaf: true
            });
        });
        ttI.removeAll(true);
    }
   ...
```

A segunda `tree` não tem nada, somente é carregada com os novos valores adicionados na primeira `tree`.

Comment: atualizei meu post com o código

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Posta o código da primeira store e o nome da segunda store. Olha esse código que você postou eu nao consigo nem começar a te ajudar a não ser em dizer pra você o usar o listener `add` da sua primeira store.